# in sql server 2000 use concatenation of string and variable inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to copy an existing table into a new one, but the name of the new table will be the name of the old one concatenated with the value of the parameter @vNum

```
Create proc copy_Boleto_num @vNum int
as
declare @bol varchar(10) 
set @bol = 'boleto_' + convert(varChar(4), @vNum)

print @bol

if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[@bol]') and
   OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
   drop table [@bol]

 select * into  [@bol] from boleto
 print @bol + ' dropped and created'
 select * from [@bol]
```

whith the value given to @vNum as 254  I an trying to create a table called Boleto_254

interesting that the print instruction gives me the the value Boleto_254

see massege:

```
boleto_254

(33 row(s) affected)
boleto_254 dropped and created

(33 row(s) affected)
```

But the result table is named @bol

need help
Thanks
Dov

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using/targeting SQL Server 2000? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Also, your query isn't working because you cannot parametrise object names, only data values. You must use Dynamic SQL if you want that (and in the process lose out on query plan caching)

Answer (score 0):

First, the requisite:  You are using software that has not been supported in *years*.   You really need to upgrade to a *supported* version of SQL Server.  You have a bunch to choose from.

In any case, the issue is that you need dynamic SQL.  I think this will work in SQL Server 2000:

```
Create proc copy_Boleto_num @vNum int
as
begin
    declare @bol varchar(10) ;
    set @bol = 'boleto_' + convert(varChar(4), @vNum);

    print @bol;

    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    set @sql = replace('drop table [@name]', '@name', @bol);

    if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id(@bol) and
       OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
    begin
       exec(@sql);
    end;

    set @sql = replace('select * into [@name] from boleto', '@name', @bol);
    exec(@sql);
    print @bol + ' dropped and created'
    set @sql = replace('select * from [@name]', '@name', @bol);
    exec(@sql);
end;
```

Then, rush out and get a version of SQL Server 2016 or 2014.  They are much more powerful than SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Hi, It works perfect on sql server 12 that I use, but not on sql 2005 standard. here is the message:         boleto_254
Server: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark before the character string 'bolet'.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'bolet'.
boleto_254 dropped and created
Server: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark before the character string 'bolet'.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'bolet'.
Stored Procedure: mala2.dbo.copy_boleto_num
 Return Code = 0

Comment: @dovk179 . . . I think the problem is the check for the object's existence (I just fixed it to use the variable.  I can't think of any quoting thing that would work in SQL Server 2012 but not in SQL Server 2005.